# Regex Expression To Match Special Characters And Numbers

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) to see if a string contains any special characters, numbers or anything else but letters.

For example I have a string `"This is a 5 string #"`. Now I would need a [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) to see if this string contains any special characters like `#` or numbers like `5`.

I'm not familiar with using [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) approaches.

Comment: Have you had a look at http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and tried to learn the basics?

Comment: What are your needs exactly then? Because what you just stated is completely googleable and found in every basic regex tutorial

Comment: I'm reading now some tutorials on regex expressions. I found something similar to what I need, in fact it is very basic, only that first I had the impression that I must look for the numbers and special characters in the string, only to find that I should only match letters from a-z A-Z ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `.test()` method

```
if ("This is a 5 string #".test(/[^a-z]/i)) { ... }
```

this will find if some symbols different from a-z and A-Z are inside the string. Note also that this regexp won't accept accented letters. in that case you will need a more refined regexp like

```
/[^a-zA-Z\u00C0-\u00D6\u00D8-\u00F6\u00F8-\u02FF]/
```

see a unicode table to choose what symbols are acceptable in your string

http://unicode.org/charts/

Comment: Yes, I thought of .test method too ... thanks for the expression :)

Answer (score 1):

The basics you want is something like `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/`
 this will tell you if your string as any charachters of a to z upper and lowercase.

There are tons off resources online to learn more about regex, a good resource is http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html