# How can I check if a string contains only a particular set of special characters in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8688208/regex-expression-to-match-special-characters-and-numbers) question provides a solution to match special characters and numbers.
What should be the regular expression that I need to use to match only a particular set of special characters in Javascript?

For instance, I want to check if a string contains anything other than following special characters `~!@#$`.

I've tried the below code, but I'm not sure if it is correct:

```
var myRegex = \~!@#\;  
var testString = "!!@@ABCD[]";  // This contains [], so it must be false  
if(myRegex.test(testString))  
{  
   //do something  
}
```

Do let me know the reason for downvoting so that I can avoid my mistakes in the future.
Downvoting without any reason won't help either of us to learn anything. Thanks.

Comment: reading a basic tutorial about regex will solve the problem.

Comment: It's not only not correct, it won't even pass the most basic syntax check. What is `\~!@#\\` supposed to mean with those backslashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to check if a string contains anything `other than` following special characters `~!@#$`

You can try below regex

```
^[^~!@#$]+$
```

Pattern explanation:

```
  ^                        the beginning of the line
  [^~!@#$]+                any character except: 
                           '~', '!', '@', '#', '$' 
                           (1 or more times )
  $                        the end of the line
```

---

[Learn more...](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) about **`character sets`**

[image]

Comment: What if the set of special characters contain `^` ?

Comment: It is used for **excpet** for example `[a-z]` is used to match `a` to `z` whereas `[^a-z]` is used just to negate it means other than `a` to `z`

Comment: Yes, I know that. But, can I include that also in the list? Say, `[^!@#$^&*]` ?

Comment: Have a look at [demo](http://regex101.com/r/nH2gW1/7)

Comment: In addition, you might want to escape any regex related characters that you're trying to check for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593637/how-to-escape-regular-expression-in-javascript